# Missing Variable Error in Django Form After Form Submission

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I added a newsletter sign-up form to the footer area of my site and such had to use an inclusion_tag because I couldn't bind it to a view. It works well and as expected, but I have a strange thing happening that I apparently am not smart enough to figure out myself :)

After the form is submitted, I receive the email confirmation, but two things happen:

1. The Django Success Message doesn't appear until after I manually refresh the page.
2. Where my form sits, there are syntax 'Missing Variable' errors.  I included a screenshot for reference and my form code is below. The form fields re-appear and errors go away after refreshing the page again.

[image]

**home_tags.py**

```
@register.inclusion_tag('pages/tags/footer_newsletter_signup.html', takes_context=True)
def footer_newsletter_signup(context):
    request = context['request']
    title = 'Newsletter Signup'
    form = MailingListForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        mailing_list_full_name = form.cleaned_data.get('mailing_list_full_name')
        mailing_list_phone = form.cleaned_data.get('mailing_list_phone')
        mailing_list_email = form.cleaned_data.get('mailing_list_email')
        mailing_list_subject = 'Submission from Newsletter Signup'
        mailing_list_message = 'Yes, please add me to marketing emails.'
        from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
        recipient_list = [from_email, 'charles@studiorooster.com']
        ctx = {
            'mailing_list_subject': mailing_list_subject,
            'mailing_list_full_name': mailing_list_full_name,
            'mailing_list_email': mailing_list_email,
            'mailing_list_phone': mailing_list_phone,
            'mailing_list_message': mailing_list_message
        }

        message = get_template('pages/newsletter_signup_email.html').render(Context(ctx))
        msg = EmailMessage(mailing_list_subject, message, to=recipient_list, from_email=from_email)
        msg.content_subtype = 'html'
        msg.send()

        messages.success(request, "Thank you, you've been added to our list.")
        return HttpResponse('/')

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'title': title,
    }
    return context
```

**footer_newsletter_signup.html**

```
<form action='' method='POST' role='form' class="form-inline">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group">
    {{ form.mailing_list_full_name }}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    {{ form.mailing_list_phone }}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    {{ form.mailing_list_email }}
  </div>
  <button class="button button-lg button-square button-pasific hover-ripple-out" type='submit'>Subscribe</button>
</form>
```

Then I just add the tag to my template like:

```
{% footer_newsletter_signup %}
```

Comment: Why are you processing from inside a tag?

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev Not sure exactly what you're asking, but I added my form to the original question.

Comment: `form = MailingListForm(request.POST or None) if form.is_valid(): ...` This code should be in view not in tag.

Comment: Ok, so here is where I am confused. I have a dozen views and this form is a  Call-to-Action form that sits at the top of the footer.  How do I bind this form to every view without repeating the code everywhere?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering this

> Ok, so here is where I am confused. I have a dozen views and this form is a Call-to-Action form that sits at the top of the footer. How do I bind this form to every view without repeating the code everywhere? Thank you for your help.

You need to create separate view to handle this form and provide `action` param in `form` tag pointing to this view.

Here is general idea, code my not work

```
#template
<form action='{% url "send-mail" %}' method='POST' role='form' class="form-inline">
  ...
#views
def send_mail(request):
    form = MailingListForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            mailing_list_full_name = form.cleaned_data.get('mailing_list_full_name')
            mailing_list_phone = form.cleaned_data.get('mailing_list_phone')
            mailing_list_email = form.cleaned_data.get('mailing_list_email')
            mailing_list_subject = 'Submission from Newsletter Signup'
            mailing_list_message = 'Yes, please add me to marketing emails.'
            from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
            recipient_list = [from_email, 'charles@studiorooster.com']
            ctx = {
                'mailing_list_subject': mailing_list_subject,
                'mailing_list_full_name': mailing_list_full_name,
                'mailing_list_email': mailing_list_email,
                'mailing_list_phone': mailing_list_phone,
                'mailing_list_message': mailing_list_message
            }

            message = get_template('pages/newsletter_signup_email.html').render(Context(ctx))
            msg = EmailMessage(mailing_list_subject, message, to=recipient_list, from_email=from_email)
            msg.content_subtype = 'html'
            msg.send()

            messages.success(request, "Thank you, you've been added to our list.")
            return HttpResponse('/')

#tags
@register.inclusion_tag('pages/tags/footer_newsletter_signup.html', takes_context=True)
def footer_newsletter_signup(context):
    title = 'Newsletter Signup'
    form = MailingListForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'title': title,
    }
    return context

#url
url('r^send-mail/$', send_mail, name='send-email')
```